# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i, ora-01861, to-date

I'm pretty sure this is something really silly.

Instead of spending another 10 minutes with this ( or better said, while I spend another 10 minutes with this )  I'll ask it here in parallel.

What's wrong with the following statement:

```
select to_date( '30/10/2009 18:27:35', 'DD/MM/YYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```

The error message is:

```
Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

SQLState:  22008
ErrorCode: 1861
Position: 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`'DD/MM/YYY HH24:MI:SS'`

Try this with four Y's

`'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'`